# In app billing setup returns code 3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Im trying to get In-App Billing to work. I have followed the tutorial from http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/ somewhat, and I get purchases working. Although from both my testing devices at some point it stops to work. What also stops to work at the same time is paid apps in full and Ill only see free apps.

From my developer account testing against the reserved products, i found out the reason that my account had somehow been logged out? And when logging back in it work, happy with that :)

From my testing account against the published product I got a message saying "product not availabe from merchant" or something like that. Then that account is crashed (not available to make purchases) and I cannot get market working again.

I have:
- Verified multiple accounts does not exist
- Ensured my account is still logged on to market (the case from developer account) 
- Cleared google play cache
- Removed the account as testing account 
- Restarted the device

Any ideas here? I could understand if my app wouldn't work due to poor coding, but what is this behaviour, diasabling the market for the account? Could google play block my account due to spam? And does 10 IAB setups or so count as spam?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Developers cannot purchase their own products. So you can build a signed version of your apk and test it on a device who's primary account is not tied to your developer account. I had to use my wife's phone to test my IAP. Also note that you have to wait a while before your products (SKU's) will be available.

Comment: Thanks, but if I did not make myself clear this is pretty much what I already know. When I test on my developer account I test purchases via the static codes supplied by google for testing, and them works fine.. until I get the IAB setup failed message (Happend again just now, and now I cant get that to work for purchases once again, above solution by logging in seems to be some other random problem).

Comment: As info, if I have done some strange editing, this is my first post here, and the edit buttons are in strange places, sorry about any mistakes on my side...

Comment: @Smurf75 Yep.  I saw it.  I removed the errant entry you made earlier to the post.  It should be okay now.  Thanks for making the effort!

Comment: +1 for helping me out with the forum. I still have my problem though ;)